# I want [] image to be displayed as my cursor?

Tags: image, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, custom-cursor

I am working on WinRT/XAML Windows Store application.
I want to change the curson/pointer to change from dot to [].
Later I want to give image to the cursor.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are articles on using custom cursor files in Windows Store apps, like this:

[CustomCursors in Windows 8 CSharp Metro Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2012/08/02/customcursors-in-windows-8-csharp-metro-applications.aspx). The gist is you need to create a native dll that will have the cursor resource in it.

You could then use an attached property to set the cursor for a specific control as [in the `FrameworkElementExtensions.Cursor` property here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs).